# Create a 40x40 matrix with conditions

Tags: matlab, octave

I want to create a 40x40 matrix in matlab with these conditions.

[\ A_{i,j} ]

=

> 1

if $i+2 \le j \le i+12$ or $j+12-39 > i > j+2-39$

> 0 otherwise

PS I let the element in the upper left corner have index _{0,0} and the one in the right bottom corner _{39,39}

(Actually, I want to do it in Octave, but I think those are almost always the same)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a vectorized approach. It uses [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) to generate all combinations of your *i* and *j* indices, and then applies your conditions:

```
[ii, jj] = ndgrid(0:39);
A = ((ii+2 <= jj) & (jj <= ii+12)) | ((jj+12-39>ii) & (ii>jj+2-39));
```